# Deleting a records in gridview error message box in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I generate an error message box when a user delete a record's associated with other records in the tables in gridview? If a user delete a category from TblCategory I want it to generate an error message box that will inform the user that there are still books under that category and will not delete unless he removes all records associated to that category.

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="categoryid" DefaultMode="Insert"
        DataSourceID="categoryDataSource">

        <EditItemTemplate>

            categoryid:
            <asp:Label ID="categoryidLabel1" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("categoryid") %>' />
            <br />

            Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="nameTextBox" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' />
            <br />

            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                &nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />

        </EditItemTemplate>

        <InsertItemTemplate>

            Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="nameTextBox" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="nameTextBox" ValidationGroup="createcategory">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />

            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="createcategory" 
                CommandName="Insert" Text="Create" />
                <asp:Button ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </InsertItemTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="New" Text="New" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                CommandName="New" Text="New" />
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="categoryDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LibrarySystemConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [TblCategory] WHERE [categoryid] = @categoryid" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [TblCategory] ([name]) VALUES (@name)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [categoryid], [name] FROM [TblCategory]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [TblCategory] SET [name] = @name WHERE [categoryid] = @categoryid">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="categoryid" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="categoryid" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</p>
<h4 class="style6">
    List of Categories</h4>
<p>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
        DataKeyNames="categoryid" DataSourceID="categoryDataSource" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" RowDeleted="grdCategory_RowDeleted">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: How about not providing the delete option in first place for those Category...  Try grabbing the boolean whether association exists and display delete to only those, where the boolean value is false.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `RowDeleted` event of gridview that you need to use. It will fire after the execution of the `Delete` command. This will fire whether your row is deleted successfully or not.

```
 protected void grdCategory_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        if (e.Exception.InnerException.Message == "ContainBooks") // I suppose, you will throw "ContainBooks" in exception from your BLL when your category Having books
        {
            //Display Warning Message Here, that You can Delete
        }
        else
        {
            lblException.Text = e.Exception.InnerException.Message;
        }

        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
    else if (e.AffectedRows != 0)
    {
        //Display Success Message that Record Deleted Successfully
    }
}
```

> The `RowDeleted` event is raised when a row's `Delete` button is clicked, but after the `GridView` control deletes the row. This enables you to provide an event-handling method that performs a custom routine, such as checking the results of the delete operation, whenever this event occurs.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleted.aspx)

Comment: I have provide you much more clean code. I don't think so you feel difficulty. Because this what I have used in many applications.

Comment: No error but it doesn't show any message box. It only show a Server Error in "/" Application DELETE statement conflicted with COLUMN REFERENCE constraint 'FK_TblBooks_TblCategory'. The conflict occurred in database 'LibrarySystem', table 'TblBooks', column 'categoryid'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Are you not using any BLL ? you are use query directly in SQL Datasoure ? if that is the case, Debug and set breakpoint in Deleted event and check what e.Exception contains, if error thrown ?

Comment: Ok I'll try. Might take a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void MyGridView_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception is SqlException)
        {
            int sqlErrorCode = ((SqlException)e.Exception).Number;

            if (sqlErrorCode == 547)
            {
                // SQL Error Code 547:
                //    "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE 
                //     constraint "FK_SomeTable"
                // 
                //  You can display a friendly error message here and tell
                //  the system that you have handled the error
                // 
                myTextBox_ErrorMessage.Text = @"Data could not be deleted.
                                              Other data in the system is 
                                              currently referencing this data.";
                e.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```